# DocuSign API - Create Envelope for Template with a witness

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on a DocuSign document that we've uploaded as a Template. The document has 2 fields for a Witness at the bottom - their name and signature as shown here:

[image]

In the DocuSign Template editor I've created a single role and added the tabs/fields like this:

[image]

however the Sign tab uses the recipients signature. I've never worked with using a witness before and can't work out how I can provide the option in either the Template or the API envelope request (or both) for including a witness to sign and enter their name. We won't know their name/email etc at the time of sending the envelope.

Do I need to create a new role for the Witness here and add the tabs for that Role? We were hoping the signer could just handover to the Witness to enter their name and sign when the signer has completed signing the document.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [live example](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Witness) of a witness to a signer recipient.

For a template,  you should be able to add the witness recipient via composite template technique.

Here is an [example](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Template%20with%20added%20tabs) of modifying a template's recipient. In your case, you'll **add** a new recipient (the witness)

Comment: Thanks that's definitely helpful. I'm just trying to workout how do I associate the 2 tabs that I need the Witness to complete (Witness Name and Witness Signature) to the Witness. Do I need to create a new Role for them and assign those tabs to their role?